# Remove an IPTable Rule

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm having troubles removing this `ipables` rule in Ubuntu:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

I've tried using the `-D` attribute but with no success. How can I remove this? I've tried flushing the tables but that didn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add output of `iptables -t nat -nvL`

Answer (score 4):

It should just be:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

Or try to find line numbers (iptables -L --line-numbers), and use:

```
sudo iptables -D [number]
```

The second should definitely work.

Or try a third thing:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
```

... you should be lucky with one of these.